# Buildpack": Failure: (ID: 224c5ea3) Failed to run /bin/build: couldn't find runtime version from runtimeconfig.json

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, c#-6.0, buildpack

Hi Am trying to deploy a test project using Google Cloud Platform with Buildpack deployments. However, the deployment process fails, even though the runtimeconfig.json has runtime version defined. Is there something that is missing from the json file. The file is automatically generated by the dotnet (setting GenenerateRuntimeConfiguration=true in .csproj file). Has anyone encountered the same problem and found any workarounds?

```
Step #0 - "Buildpack":   cat /workspace/bin/TestServerConsole.runtimeconfig.json
Step #0 - "Buildpack":   {
Step #0 - "Buildpack":     "runtimeOptions": {
Step #0 - "Buildpack":       "tfm": "net6.0",
Step #0 - "Buildpack":       "framework": {
Step #0 - "Buildpack":         "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
Step #0 - "Buildpack":         "version": "6.0.0"
Step #0 - "Buildpack":       },
Step #0 - "Buildpack":       "configProperties": {
Step #0 - "Buildpack":         "System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdater.IsSupported": false
Step #0 - "Buildpack":       }
Step #0 - "Buildpack":     }
Step #0 - "Buildpack":   }
Step #0 - "Buildpack": Done "dotnet publish -nologo --verbosity minimal --configuration R..." (7.695605258s)
Step #0 - "Buildpack": Determining entrypoint from output directory bin and project file TestServerConsole/TestServerConsole.csproj
Step #0 - "Buildpack": === .NET - Runtime (google.dotnet.runtime@0.9.1) ===
Step #0 - "Buildpack": Found runtimeconfig.json file: TestServerConsole/bin/Release/net6.0/TestServerConsole.runtimeconfig.json
Step #0 - "Buildpack": Using runtimeconfig file "TestServerConsole/bin/Release/net6.0/TestServerConsole.runtimeconfig.json"
Step #0 - "Buildpack": Failure: (ID: 224c5ea3) Failed to run /bin/build: couldn't find runtime version from runtimeconfig.json: &dotnet.RuntimeConfigJSON{RuntimeOptions:dotnet.runtimeOptions{TFM:"net6.0", Framework:dotnet.framework{Name:"Microsoft.NETCore.App", Version:"6.0.0"}, Frameworks:[]dotnet.framework(nil), ConfigProperties:dotnet.configProperties{SystemGCServer:false}}}
Step #0 - "Buildpack": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #0 - "Buildpack": Sorry your project couldn't be built.
```